# .goutputstream-XXXXX - possible to relocate?

Tags: unix, linux-kernel, gedit

I've been trying to create a union file system for a college project.  One of its features that differentiates it from [unionfs](http://unionfs.filesystems.org/) is the fact that there are no copy-ups. This means that if a file is located in a certain branch, it will remain there even if it is written to.

But my current problem with that is the fact that .goutputstream-XXXXX are created, renamed, and deleted whenever a write operation occurs. This is actually OK if the file being written to is in the highest priority branch (i.e. the default branch where files can be created), but makes my kernel crash if I try to write to a file in a lower branch.

How do I deal with this? How can I rig it so that all .goutputstream-XXXXX files are written to only one location?  These .goutputstream-XXXXX files seem to be intricately connected to the files they correspond too, and seem to work only the same directory as the file being written to.

I also noticed that .goutputstream-XXXXX files appear when a directory is read. What are they for, anyway?

Comment: Is your project based directly on UnionFS or have you created your own backing store?

Comment: What application are you using to write to files? It sounds as though you may be using some sort of GNOME-based editor (gedit?) that does strange things to write to files atomically. Try testing with shell operations (*e.g*, `echo "Hello world" >> afile`) first.

Comment: Making a server here, a file `.goutputstream-XXXXX` is created each time a UNIX socket is created, and should go away when the socket is closed, and or when the parent program is terminated. When taking care to close them properly they fade away quickly. They takes sometimes few minutes after a more brutal SIGINT to kill the parent program. A well written program should take care of SIGINT and do some cleaning. When the system is shutdown, similarly, the files stay permanently because they wasn't garbaged by the system. Allow more time to shutdown, and closing everything properly should be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.goutputstream-XXXXX created by gedit and there is no simple way (menu or settings) to relocate them.

Answer (score 3):

There has been a bug submitted to the ubuntu launchpad in which the creation of .goutputstream-xxxxx files is discussed.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/984785

From what i see now, these files are created when shutting down without preceding logout, but several other sources may occur, like evince or maybe gedit.
maybe lightdm has something to do with the creation of these files.

which distribution did you use?
maybe changing the distribution would help.